# Return errors with custom error object format

Tags: feathersjs

I'm trying to define my own error format to be returned in the response.
I have written my own middleware:

```
function catchAndLogErrors(app) {
    return function (err, req, res, next) {
       // stuff happening...
       throw new Error(err.message, {name: err.name, code: err.code, className: err.className, info: err.info, data: err.data});
    };
}
```

and then in `/src/middleware/index.js` I've commented out the `handler` and put my own middleware:

```
const handler = require('feathers-errors/handler');
const catchAndLogErrors = require('my-middleware');
...

app.use(catchAndLogErrors(app));
// app.use(handler());
```

but I get the error returned as HTML and it's actually only the message and the stacktrace, but none of the other properties.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you commented out the [Feathers error handler](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/errors.html#rest-express-errors) you will have to implement your own [Express error handler](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html) where you format the error and send the response (instead of just throwing it) similar to this (if you want to send JSON):

```
function catchAndLogErrors(app) {
    return function (err, req, res, next) {
      res.json(err);
    };
}
```

The real Feathers way for modifying errors of service method calls are [error hooks](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/hooks.html). They allow you to modify `hook.error` to the response you need, e.g. with an [application wide hook](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/hooks.html#application-hooks) that applies to all service calls:

```
app.hooks({
  error(hook) {
    const err = hook.error;

    //change `hook.error` to the modified error    
    hook.error = new Error(err.message, {
      name: err.name,
      code: err.code,
      className: err.className,
      info: err.info,
      data: err.dat
    });
  }
});
```